# Adding JPanels to JPanel array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jpanel

I have declared an array:

```
private javax.swing.JPanel[] panelArray = new javax.swing.JPanel[3];
```

I also have 3 panels: panel0, panel1 and panel2. Can I add these panels to the array? i.e

```
panelArray[0] = panel0;
panelArray[1] = panel1;
panelArray[2] = panel2;
```

And then manipulate the arrays like this?

```
boolean[] myBools; .... then set them as true/false
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    if(myBools[i])
        panelArray[i].setVisible(true)
}
```

Because that does not work for me

Answer (score 6):

On my side it's working fine, in this program :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyPanel
{   
    private JPanel[] panelArray = new JPanel[3];
    private boolean[] myBools = new boolean[]{false, false, false};
    private int counter = 0; 
    private int prvPanelCounter = 0;
    private Timer timer;
    private ActionListener timerAction = new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            counter++;
            if (counter > 2)
                counter = 0;
            myBools[counter] = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
            {
                if (myBools[i])
                {
                    panelArray[i].setVisible(myBools[i]);                   
                    panelArray[prvPanelCounter].setVisible(myBools[prvPanelCounter]);
                    myBools[i] = false; 
                    prvPanelCounter = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Locate Mouse Position");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel0 = new JPanel();
        panel0.setOpaque(true);
        panel0.setBackground(Color.BLUE);       
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setOpaque(true);
        panel1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setOpaque(true);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        panelArray[0] = panel0;
        panelArray[1] = panel1;
        panelArray[2] = panel2;

        JComponent contentPane = (JComponent) frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        frame.add(panel0);  
        frame.add(panel1);  
        frame.add(panel2);  
        panel0.setVisible(myBools[counter]);
        panel1.setVisible(myBools[counter]);
        panel2.setVisible(myBools[counter]);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        timer = new Timer(1000, timerAction);
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String\u005B\u005D args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new MyPanel().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for that :-). A simple question, though, How can you change your flair (that pic next to your name), Can I do that too ?

Comment: congrats to the silver Swing badge :-)

Comment: Thankyou, just today I got that :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw  If I can infer correctly what you mean as well as the relative URLs, see [User nIcE cOw Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/1057230)

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Nah, actually, what I saw, is that flair by default is changed to something else, like your flair as given by stackoverflow, can I have that flair pic too , or I have to stick to the one assigned to me, Thanks for this link, though, seems like I hadn't seen this change pic thingy before

Comment: I understand 'flair' to be a slightly different thing to the image that identifies us in posts & questions.  E.G. You can see my currently chosen 'flair' (that includes the image, but has rep. as well) on the [About page](http://athompson.info/about.html) at my site.  It is just before the **Science & Technology** section on the right.  DYM the flair, or just the image used in it?

Comment: If I can change the flair to green, orange, red, to my taste everyday, that will be good, like one day I like someone's green, the other day slightish grey flair, they all are good

Comment: @trasNGOs : Ohh yeah, with some help, else who gets time to do that :-). Even, the day before yesterday I found out, how to check, who edited my posts :-)

Comment: @trashgod : Ohh yeah, with some help, else who gets time to do that :-). Even, the day before yesterday I found out, how to check, who edited my posts :-)

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do can be done, but here's a few points to bear in mind:

1. Make sure you initialise the JPanels before referencing them.
2. The statement "panelArray[i].setVisible(true)" needs a semicolon after it.
3. None of these panels will be visible unless you add them to another component, such as a JFrame.
4. Rather than state javax.swing.JPanel, you could just import the JPanel at the top of the page and refer to it as simply JPanel.
5. Your "if" statement is unnecessary.  Just do .setVisible(myBools[i]);

Hope these were of some help to you.

Comment: +1 for point 5, LOL I missed that with my open eyes, but you caught that, too easily :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  Did you really not initialize the `myBools` array with `new` ?